# Simulate Mouse Events linux

Tags: linux, mouse, simulate

I have tried hard to find a C/C++ library to simulate mouse events in Linux, but cannot find one. Can someone suggest an easy library for the same?

Comment: It depends if you are thinking of some [X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11) based desktop application or not.

Answer (score 3):

There are two methods:

1. You can generate ["synthetic" events](http://www.doctort.org/adam/nerd-notes/x11-fake-keypress-event.html)

   The mouse buttons are handled very similar to keys on the keyboard, so it should be simple to adapt this code. Note that applications can find out about this by looking at the `IsSynthetic` field in the event. Xterm for example ignores synthetic events for security reasons.
2. You can use the [XTEST extension](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/Xext/xtestlib.pdf).

   This allows sending events with `IsSynthetic` set to `False`, and hence full simulation, but the extension is normally disabled or restricted.